# Need help with C# Sockets - Connection is working locally, but not from another network

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, xna

I'm making a multiplayer game in XNA 4.0, using the .NET socket classes.

Since I had never programmed sockets before, I wrote a little client/server program, and tested it locally (client and server on two different computers) and they worked just fine.

However, when I tried to connect between two different networks (The server was at my house and the client was running at my friend's house who lives 5 minutes away) the client couldn't connect.

I used the Socket.BeginConnect() method, and .NET didn't throw any exceptions (If the target computer refused the connection, then .NET would have thrown a SocketException)
There were no firewalls on either computer.

Any idea why this happened?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    public void connect(String ipAddress, int port)
    {
        lock(_locker)
        {
            if (!_connecting)
            {
                _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);

                try
                {
                    _socket.BeginConnect(endpoint, doConnect, null);
                    _connecting = true;
                } catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    // what happen? SOMEONE SET US UP THE BOMB!
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What was the network configuration on the destination side? Any chance the connection was blocked by your friend's router?

Comment: What address did the server bind on? `0.0.0.0:port` or something else?

Comment: I made sure that the server binded on the right ip address, and on the right port

Comment: Try using `Socket.Connect` so (if) you'll get an exception there, that might point you in the right direction

Comment: How would my friend's router block the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your friend connects to the Net through a router, the router is almost certainly blocking all unsolicited incoming traffic. That is how NAT routers work.

To get the router to accept incoming connections to a given port and pass them on to one of the machines attached to the router, your friend will have to set up port forwarding.

[This site](http://portforward.com/) provides instructions on how to do this and covers a large number of router manufacturers and models.